openapi / swagger examples are not displayed
I'm using spring-boot 3.2
here is my dependencies:
pom.xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
             <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>7.6.0</version>
...


so I want to display examples under one schema. Here is my test endpoint:
openapi.yaml
paths:
  /tests:
    get:
      summary: 'test'
      description: 'test'
      operationId: getTestData
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'test'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
              examples:
                test-example:
                  value: 'test-data'

and in swagger I got:
UI IMAGE
and also v3/api-docs also dont contain examples
API-DOCS IMAGE
generated TestApi interface:
TESTAPI INTERFACE IMAGE
example instead of examples also not working. examples for the parameters and requests also not working.
but example on the schema level is working:
schemas:
    Email:
      type: string
      format: email
      description: 'User''s email'
      pattern: '^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,}$'
      example: 'example@gmail.com'


After you import Swagger you should configure it.
Here is one basic example:
@Configuration
public class SwaggerAPI {

  public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${application.description}") String description) {
    return new OpenAPI().info(new Info()
        .title(description)
        .version("2.0")
        .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms")
        .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")));
  }

Now you can access the swagger API here:
http://localhost:{servicePort}/swagger-ui/index.html?continue

